# Share AI key between between multiple web apps and services?

Tags: azure-application-insights

We got an app suite that consist of multiple web apps, web api's and windows services. Today we have one instrumentation key per webapp / api / service, in addition one per environment. This gets a bit messy and we're thinking it would have been better to only one shared key per environment.

Are there other ways to aggregate and visulize the AI data from multiple keys, or should be move all our keys into one shared?

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, there are several considerations. To illustrate, let's assume you have two "components" A and B

1. **Visibility scope** - do you analyze telemetry about A and B separately or together. Putting into a single resource (single iKey) will enable you to aggregate across A and B (e.g. see a total number of requests for A and B together). On the other side, to view separately (e.g. just requests to A), you will have to apply filters, which may impact the value of out of the box journeys we provide. If you choose to keep separate, you can still "mix and match" on dashboards, but not aggregate across. We are working to enable
2. **Access control** - do you want certain people only access telemetry about A and not B
3. **Pricing** - as we charge per app, you should consider this aspect
4. **Lifecycle** - you may want your telemetry containers to match the topology of your deployment artifacts

Comment: We're probably going with option 1 for our app. Several APIs / microservices under one key/container. It would be nice if App Insights App Map could understand that each site is a separate "server", and also understand that an "external dependency" (API call) is actually internal and to the same key...

Comment: We're using a single AI resource for multiple App Services (i.e. shared iKey). It works great with custom events and/or trace logging (we're using log4net AI appender). 

However when it comes to dependency data it seems to me like we're only getting dependency data for a single App Service (kind of obvious when looking at the Application Map).
Do you know if there is such a restriction? When starting to monitor a live Azure web app (without adding the SDK at build time) I believe there is such a restriction.

Comment: This isn't accurate. The pricing for App Insights now charges per GB of telemetry data sent, with free tier including 1 GB per month, and paid tier including 4.8 GB per month. Additionally, paid tier includes fee of $15/node/month. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/application-insights/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dashboard in order to organize your data. Dashboard can contain metrics from different applications so your data will be very organized in one page.

You can read more about dashboards here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-dashboards/

Thanks,
Yair