# Can I use single Application Instrumentation key used for all applications developed in different languages?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am developing multiple applications in different languages like Java, Node.js, Angularjs and ASP.net. I want to use Application insights for tracking my applications telemetry. But I have these questions:

1. Should I use single application insights resource instrumentation key for all applications or should I create individual application insights resources?
2. When I chosen the Asp.net language for creating  application insights resource. Is this application insights resource will collect all telemetry from all application in different languages or not?

Would you please tell me what are pros and cons, if I use single AI or multiple AIs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share AI key between between multiple web apps and services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265633/share-ai-key-between-between-multiple-web-apps-and-services)

Answer (score 1):

Oleg provided good considerations for overall single/multi ikeys here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39339304/3646920

Regarding shared ikey for web services written in different languages (not to be confused with backend + web app sharing the same ikey - this scenario is supported). Application Insights optimizes experience based on selected application. It means that though data will be available from all different web services and all languages, some functionality will not light up correctly.

Another way to think about it is that this setup is getting less tested compared to other usage patterns.